# want regular expression for \\n and \\t

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have source string

```
string source = "hemant \\\n test new line \\\t test tab";
```

want string using regular expression

```
string destination = "hemant test new line test tab"
```

(Here i just replace \n and \t with " " i.e white space)

So i had try

```
string destination = Regex.Replace(source, "[\\\n\\\\t]", " ");
```

this gives me  destination = hema  test ew line   es   ab "

Here it remove the \\n and \\t. But remove the nt from hemant n from new

```
string destination = Regex.Replace(source, "[\\n\\t]", " ");
```

this don't do anything

Comment: Does your string contain a backslash followed by a newline character or tab, or just a backslash followed by the letters n or t?  The answer you accepted would not work for the string you have.  Should it be `string source = "hemant \\n test new line \\t test tab";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
string destination = Regex.Replace(source, @"(?:\\n)|(?:\\t)", " ");
```

or even more simple:

```
string destination = Regex.Replace(source, @"\\[nt]", " ");
```

Comment: This results in 3 spaces between "hemat" and "test" assuming that the original string should be `string source = "hemant \\n test new line \\t test tab";`.  It results in something completely different for the actual string posted by the OP.

Comment: @"\s\\\[nt]\s" will also replace the preceding and following whitespace in this case. I simply took the partial answer he provided and made it work.

Answer (score 0):

`"[\\\n\\\\t]"` is a *class* that describes `\`  `n` and `t` as individual characters so you lose all `n` & `t` characters.

Use: `"\\\\\\n|\\\\\\t"`

Answer (score -1):

You can just use `string.Replace` for that.

```
destination = source.Replace("\\\n", "").Replace("\\\t", "");
```

But note that will leave two spaces between "hemat" and "test", as well as between "line" and "test".  If you want to compress the spaces as well you can use this regular expression.

```
var destination = Regex.Replace(source, @"\s*(\\\n|\\\t)\s*", " ");
```

Notice the use of `@` so you don't have to double up on the backslashes.

Or assuming your string is actually

```
source = "hemant \\n test new line \\t test tab";
```

That is a backslash character followed by the letter "n" and a backslash followed by the letter "t". Then you could do something like this.

```
var destination = Regex.Replace(source, @"\s*\\[nt]\s*", " ");
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `source.Replace("\\", " ").Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\t", " ")`; no need for regex here.

Comment: This would actually remove any instance of a backslash, newline, or tab instead of only a backslash followed by a newline, or tab.  But apparently the OP was looking to replace a backslash followed by an "n" or "t".  But in general I agree that when possible one should avoid using regular expressions.

Comment: @juharr Well, my solution does what the OP wants to, remove \\n and \\t, although it also would replace \\. However I do not think that this is a mistake, just compare source and destination, my code would accomplish this.

Comment: Mine would too.  If you apply the accepted answer to the posted code you don't get the desired result, so I can only assume the OP posted the original string incorrectly.